# Checking whether given sets are convex or not

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

[image]

We have to check which of the following of the above is the convex set.
I tried this problem by taking the level curve of $f(x,y)$ at $c$ and plotted it and then for $y=c$, I checked all those points on $x$ axis such that $f(x,y)\geq c$ and from the definition of the convexity of a set I found that it is a convex set . Therefore $U$ is the convex set.

Is my approach correct?
Is there any other way to look at this problem ?

Comment: Hint: a set $S$ is convex if for all $x,y \in S$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ the convex combination $\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y \in S$.

Comment: Yes, I know this (See the edit in the question)

Comment: Notice $x y + x + y + 1=(x+1)(y+1)$.

Comment: Is my approach correct ?

Comment: $U$ is convex, $L$ and $I$ are not convex.